# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id

Tags: kotlin, android-fragment

Есть приложение с 1 активити и несколькими фрагментами, при запуске сразу открывается один из фрагментов. Требуется открыть дочерний фрагмент из родительского.

`MainActivity()` -> `FirstFragment()` -> `DetailFragment()`

Если в `FirstFragment()` , например, по нажатию кнопки вызвать

```
fragmentManager
    ?.beginTransaction()
    ?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, DetailFragment())
    ?.addToBackStack(null)
    ?.commit()
```

то работает все как надо, по крайней мере на первый взгляд. Но этот метод !Deprecated! `fragment_container` - это id контейнера в `main_layout.xml`

Вместо него вызываю

```
childFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, DetailFragment())
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit()
```

и по нажатию на кнопку появляется ошибка

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id ... for fragment DetailFragment ...
```

Comment: Вы не тем deprecated заменяете https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/FragmentManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`childFragmentManager` ищет внутри разметки фрагмента, а там никакого `fragment_container` нет, потому что он располагается в размете активити.

`fragmentManager` из системного пакета `android.app.*` уже давно не рекомендуется использовать ввиду того, что не на всех версиях Андроид он работает корректно.

Раньше вместо него использовали `supportFragmentManager` из Support Library, а теперь `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager` из Jetpack.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/FragmentManager